# ORA-01722 during CSV data import

Tags: oracle, csv, ora-01722

I know there are many threads on this, but I am completely stumped (yes, I am a beginner).

Table Definition:

```
CREATE TABLE BUDGET ( CHANNEL VARCHAR2(26),  STORE NUMBER(5),  REGION VARCHAR2(26),  MONTH_454_SKEY NUMBER(8),  SALES_AMOUNT NUMBER(9, 2),  SALES_COUNT NUMBER(5),  RETURN_AMOUNT NUMBER(10, 2),  RETURN_COUNT NUMBER(5),  TOTAL_ISSUANCE NUMBER(10, 2),  TOTAL_ISSUANCE_COUNT NUMBER(6),  FY_WEEK NUMBER(3),  FY NUMBER(6))
```

My table has over 36,000 rows - however I am only receiving this error for random rows. An example of the error rows:

```
INSERT INTO BUDGET (CHANNEL, STORE, REGION, MONTH_454_SKEY, SALES_AMOUNT, SALES_COUNT, RETURN_AMOUNT, RETURN_COUNT, TOTAL_ISSUANCE, TOTAL_ISSUANCE_COUNT, FY_WEEK, FY) VALUES ('Online',735.0,'SO',201601.0,4310.66,53.0,6108.24,89.0,10418.9,142.0,1.0,2016.0);
INSERT INTO BUDGET (CHANNEL, STORE, REGION, MONTH_454_SKEY, SALES_AMOUNT, SALES_COUNT, RETURN_AMOUNT, RETURN_COUNT, TOTAL_ISSUANCE, TOTAL_ISSUANCE_COUNT, FY_WEEK, FY) VALUES ('Online',738.0,'SO',201601.0,1237.86,21.0,5406.69,53.0,7472.55,74.0,1.0,2016.0);
```

I understand the meaning of the error, but don't understand why I am getting it. I only have 2 VARCHAR2 fields, 'Channel' and 'Region'. Any help would be greatly appreciated. TIA.

Comment: you say you're doing a CSV import but you show us INSERT statements instead of the actual CSV. How are you doing the CSV?

Comment: I was using the Data Import Wizard. Those two lines were part of the error code.
I thought I had replied earlier, but I found the culprit - they were in rows that were not throwing errors.

Answer (score 0):

The actual error was occurring on different rows than what was being rejected by Oracle.